# How to split an argument in bash

Tags: bash, variables, centos

I have a bash script, I can only pass 1 argument to that script, I need to split this argument in two variables.

I have tried passing the argument this way:

```
 ./script.sh aaaaa;bbbbb
```

and this is the script.sh:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env bash
 export VAR=$1
 export arrIN=(${VAR//;/ })
 echo ${arrIN[0]}
 echo ${arrIN[1]}
```

and i get error

```
 -bash: bbbbb: no se encontró la orden
```

is this split method wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use quotes while passing the argument that are separated by semicolon. When the shell sees a semicolon (`;`) on a command line, it's treated as a command separator, i.e. `./script.sh aaaaa` is treated as the first command and `bbbbb` is treated as the second command. So try like this instead:

```sh
./script.sh "aaaaa;bbbbb"
```

You can also do it like this:

```sh
IFS=';' read -r -a array <<< "aaa;bbbb"
echo "${array[0]}"
echo "${array[1]}"
```

Comment: Thank you, i missed the quotes; i also tried your suggestion and works like a charm.